# storyboard - how to display a tab view modally when user hits the tabbar?

Tags: xcode4, ios5, uitabbarcontroller, segue, uistoryboard

I have 4 items in my TabBar. One of the items is a "WorkFlowViewController". I want to show "WorkFlowViewController" modally when the user hits that tab in my TabBar, like click on the voicemail tab on Phone App.

**How to do that using segue in the storyboard?**

I tried to link(Control+mouse) the TabBarViewController with the WorkFlowViewController, Storyboard segue shows four options: 
1. relationship
2. push
3. modal
4. custom

if I choose "relationship", it will auto add tab item to the tabbar and works fine(not modally) when the user hits the tab.

if i choose "modal", it won't add the tab item to the tabbar, then the user has no where to click on the tab item. and i can't manually add tab item to my tabbar using storyboard.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You can't. TabBarViewController is a container view controller and thus only option 1 (relationship) is applicable.